# дан массив , найти число различных сумм элементов массива. Как сделать код рабочим для больших массивов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

def sums(array: list) -> int:
    combs = []

    for i in range(2, len(array)+1):
        combs += list(combinations(array, i))

    sumsSet = set([0] + array + list(map(sum, combs)))

    return len(sumsSet)

print(sums([49, 100, 98, 49, 0]))
```

Comment: а что значит составленный из части элементов - это как? приведите пример

Comment: Вам надо сосчитать число различных сумм подмножеств?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите пример того что вы считаете на списке `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, ответьте нам. Мы не знаем как вам помочь без ваших ответов.

Comment: Для массива [1,2,3] полный набор сумм — это [0, 1, 1+2, 1+3, 1+2+3, 2, 2+3, 3]. Различные суммы — это {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}. Итого 7 различных сумм.

Comment: Например, такой тест не работает уже на данной программе, мне нужно оптимизировать программу, чтобы она выыполнялась sums([2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64] + [100] * 494), - ответ 24764

Comment: этот ответ никак не относится тем, чтобы оптимизировать решение